# How can I tell whether I'm on an add or edit page in Django's Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

For the following code:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    extra = 1

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BookInline,
    ]
```

If I add a new Author through the admin, it will show me one Book entry because of the `extra=1`.  If I edit an existing Author who has one Book, the admin will show the existing book and a new field to add a new one.

**Current behaviour with Edit an Author who has 1 book:**

```
Author: Someone
Book: The book title
Book #2:
```

**Wanted behaviour with Edit an Author who has 1 book:**

```
Author: Someone
Book: The book title
```

Is it possible in the `admin.py`for the above code to check whether I'm in the add or edit page?  My goal is to set `extra=1` for add and `extra=0` for edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I just used `max_num=1` instead of `extra=1`, it solves my issue.  Here's the [reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#max-num).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could have a function that returned a conditional value based on the quantity of Books for the given inline?

Something like...

```
class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    extra = extra_count

    def extra_count(self):
        if self.model.objects.count > 0:
            return 1
        else
            return 0
```

This is sort of an odd behavior you're requesting.  Just out of curiosity, why exactly do you not want it to show an extra entry row in edit mode?

Comment: From the current requirement 1 row is needed but the model has been coded to anticipate future requirement changes. I'm not sure if it's a good practice but that's the way it is at the moment.